# Good reference for The Differntiable Slice Theorem

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I am looking for a book that will give me a good proof of The Differentiable Slice Theorem -

Suppose a compact Lie group $G$ acts smoothly on a manifold $M$. Then every orbit has a $G$-invarient tubular Neighbourhood. More precisely, there is a linear representation of $G_x$, the stabilizer of $x$, on a vector space $S$ so that $G {\times}_{G_x} S$, the twisted product, is a tubular neighbourhood of the orbit $G(x)$.

Thanks.

Comment: The wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_theorem_%28differential_geometry%29) refers to Theorem I.2.1 in a book by Audin (2004, Birkhauser), *Torus actions on symplectic manifolds*. It also links to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54799/on-a-proof-of-the-existence-of-tubular-neighborhoods